Should we specify headers as well as proper source files as CMake target sources?
When defining a CMake target which is a library or executable, resulting from compiling various source files, one can either specify just the source files, or also specify some or all of the header files they include, from within the project, as dependencies.
In his Meeting C++ 2019 talk (and also in 2018), presenter Deniz Bahadir recommends that we specify targets' C++ header files using target_sources(), with some of them being PUBLIC or INTERFACE. (Of course it doesn't really matter if one adds headers via add_executable() with the list of dependencies, or using a later target_sources() command).
Both of these seem to work fine. The question is - what are the pros and cons of specifying the headers, beyond the con of being more verbose?
Note: I'm asking specifically regarding C++, but the question stands for C or any languages which can include headers.

I specify headers because my IDE (Visual Studio) treats headers differently if you don't specify them to be part of the project.

Adding header files to your build system can sometimes allow it to provide extra warnings etc. but ofcourse it doesnt change whether the project will build.

I'm not sure if the duplicate is correct. The reasoning for adding headers in add_library is entirely different than for add_executable. For libraries, you specify public headers that should be available when that target is linked to (so that they can be included by files built under other target). For private headers or executables, I agree with drescherjm - IDEs seem to work better when headers are compiled separately, and you can get compiler errors 1 line shorter, which is always a plus.

@Yksisarvinen: The duplicate is about both add_executable and add_library. If you think that adding headers to add_library call has some advantages not listed among the answers to the duplicate question, then just add a new answer describing that.
